# Where mysterious no-break line %a0 breaking JSON coming from?

Tags: php, json, ajax, wordpress

I give up trying to solve this by myself, I need help! I have been working on a WordPress project that has a few features working with AJAX. After updating PHP to 5.6 (as the latest WordPress requested), many of my AJAX functions are broken because of a mysterious no-break line character `%a0` appearing in its response and breaking the JSON structure.

The response is from `json_encode()`.

JSON response I am getting:

```
{
     "term_id":75,
     "name":"iPhone
3G",
     "slug":"iphone-3g"
},
```

**Investigation:**

After many hours of reading about this, I tried several solutions that worked for others, but they didn't work for me.

- Turning off `magic_quotes_gpc` in php.ini
- Escape the string with `preg_replace` on the server side for all different no-break/new-line special characters
- Escape the string on client side with `str.replace`

I checked the database, and there is no `%a0` for that entry, there is a space `%20`, which is correct. I also noticed that if I remove that space, this happens to the next item that has a space `%20`.

I should also mention that this example above with the iPhone 3G is not unique. After this item, a few items are cleared (even those with space `%20`) but then it happens again later on down the latter with other items, same situation.

So it appears that PHP is replacing `%20` with `%a0` every so often.

What should I do?

Comment: What is your database's character set? And are you using htmlspecialchars? The default encoding changed in PHP 5.4 and this might be the cause of your issue.

Comment: The database is using  utf8mb4_unicode_ci. No, I am not using htmlspecialchars.

Comment: a work around.. replace all instance of linebreak after you get your json response.

Comment: @Gerrit0, you still think it is the character set? I think you might be on the right track. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Yea, I am at least 90% sure it is the character set, the problem reminds me of one I had when trying to upgrade a database using latin1 to utf8. I did some searching but couldn't find any definitive answer for where something might be going wrong though.

Comment: Can PHP update change the character set in the database? Because I have the impression that before it was utf8_general_ci.

Comment: Just upgrading PHP wouldn't change that, a wordpress update might though, out of curiosity, does running SET NAMES 'latin1' fix the issue?

Comment: I ran the command and the problem persists. I also tried changing the character set to utf8_general_ci but it didn't work either.

Comment: @Gerrit0, yikes! You'd never guess, it's Firebug in Firefox adding the special character. The error in parsing the JSON is still there, I'm working on it, it is something else. But when I ran it in Chrome, the JSON was valid. Thanks for helping me with this!

Comment: That's extremely strange! Maybe something to do with the content-type header?

Comment: No idea. I checked it and it is set to `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`, the meta tag is also set to the same charset. According to W3C Internationalization Checker tool, everything is peachy.

Comment: Just to wrap it up, in the end I had two issues: 1) the Firebug debugging tool was adding a special char for some reason and it was throwing me off. 2) a plugin update added jQuery UI autocomplete as a new feature and it was conflicting with my devbridgeAutocomplete implementations. Thanks everyone for the help! Appreciated it.